# Placing data into discontinuous bins using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, binning

I have a list of integers, and a list of discontinuous bins into which I'm trying to see if any of integers fall.

I can achieve this effect using `numpy.digitize`, and then simply disregarding any even-numbered bins, however I feel that there must be a less inelegant way to do this.

For example, simplifying the data somewhat, assume I have 4 values; `3000000`, `3275812`, `4000000`, and `4657000`. I want to see if these fall into either of two bins, `[3275812,3276886]` or `[4656730,4657770]`. At the moment I have:

```
x = np.array([3000000, 3275812, 4000000, 4657000])
bins = np.array([3275812,3276886,4656730,4657770])
inds = np.digitize(x, bins)
```

`inds` gives me the values `[0, 1, 2, 3]`, which gives me the desired result if I disregard anything which is even.

Is there anything which would explicitly give me the result `[0, 1, 0, 2]` or something similar without necessarily altering  `inds`?

Comment: I think your solution is already reasonably elegant: `np.digitize(x, bins)[1::2]` doesn't strike me as overly complex. Nor do I think you would gain much speed if, for example, you code your own solution in C.

Comment: Just be careful with discarding the even value, in the case you have 2 continous bins